# Find two-ways binding in many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a many-to-many relation `R` (two column binding table, both columns are foreign keys to the same table). Now, I'd like to find all pairs `x, y` such that `x,y in R` and `y,x in R`. What is the fastest way, how to do that when my table contains hundred thousands rows? I am using mysql.

Comment: Please post your schema, this is incomplete information. E.g., what column(s) in R do `x` and `y` point to?

Comment: @RedFilter: I believe `x` and `y` are both in `R` and they both point to some another table which is none of our concern. `R` is a friendship table or following or similar.

Comment: @Quassnoi That makes sense, I misread.

Comment: Can you show DDL (CREATE TABLE, CREATE PRIMARY KEY, CREATE FOREIGN KEY) for relation R? This way, I can answer in a more tangible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  LEAST(x, y) l, GREATEST(x, y) g
FROM    r
GROUP BY
        l, g
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Nice trick. One question, this does perform the inner join anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: @James: imagine we have two tuples: `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`. `l = LEAST(1, 2) = LEAST(2, 1) = 1`; `g = GREATEST(1, 2) = GREATEST(2, 1) = 2`. So both records will go into one group, `COUNT(*)` will be `2` and the quesy will return `1, 2`.

Comment: @James: no, it does not. It will perform what `SQL Server` calls `Eager spool`: will build an internal temporary table, indexed on `l, g`, fill it in runtime then read it back, filtering on `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Do you know about any book, links or articles covering these advanced internal things how RDBMS run queries?

Comment: @Quassnoi Absolutely OK, will look definitely ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is probably the following:

```
select (case when x < y then x else y end) as themin,
       (case when x < y then y else x end) as themax
from (select distinct x, y from R) r
group by (case when x < y then x else y end), (case when x < y then y else x end)
having count(*) > 1
```

This orders the x and y values, so when you group them, they are in canonical order regardless of the original order.

You can dispense with the "select distinct" if you know the pairs are already distinct in the R table.

The alternative is some sort of self join (either explicitly or using IN or NOT IN).  You can try different ways, but I think this is probably the fastest.

Comment: This does not work. If the following records were in R `(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 1)` your query would only return (1, 2) as a duplicate, and not (1, 3). Example on [SQL FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/849e2/1)

Comment: GerethD, could you elaborate?  It should be returning both.  (If you were refering to the typo in the group by clause, then I fixed that; the group by should have been exactly the same as the select.)

Comment: Yep, that was it. In all honesty I couldn't figure out why it wasn't returning the right results (I completely missed the typo), that is why I had to post the example fiddle to demonstrate so hopefully you would have better luck at spotting something than I did.

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    R T1
        INNER JOIN R T2
            ON T1.X = T2.Y
            AND T1.Y = T2.X
```

**ADDENDUM**

If you don't want to return duplicate rows (i.e.  1, 2 and 2, 1) you could use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    R T1
        INNER JOIN R T2
            ON T1.X = T2.Y
            AND T1.Y = T2.X
WHERE   T1.X < T1.Y;
```

However if you don't want to return duplicate rows, I suspect Quassnoi's solution may perform better, but this will depend on your data and indicies.